# problem with getting the nib file loaded in the view !

Tags: iphone, view, nib

I have created 2 views named "FirstView" and "SecondView". Both views have nib files. Now I am getting the "FirstView" nib file perfectly and then on click, I am pushing my SecondView in the window. The SecondView gets loaded but the nib is not shown in that view. Its totally white!

code to change the view:

```
svc = [[signupViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"signupViewController" bundle:nil];
[vc.view removeFromSuperview];
[window addSubview:svc.view];
```

Can anyone kindly help ?

Thanks.

-
ahsan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have two controllers, one for FirstView and a second one for SecondView. So if you are allocating your controller programmatically make sure you are initializing the secondViewController with initWithNibName: at this point when you perform presentModalViewController or pushViewController you should be able to see your nib view.

Comment: @Gabriele Added the code in the que to show how I am doing it, I believe it is the right way !

Comment: Check if the view outlet if properly connected in the nib file.

Comment: @pratikshabhisikar : I am wondering the same....can you tell me how to check it ?

Comment: I mean to say: I can see the view outlet connected to view...but since itz not working...is ther anything else I am missing ??

Comment: If I'm not wrong the view Outlet have to be setted correctly otherwise a Ahsan should have a runtime crash.
Ahsan why do you perform [svc.view removeFromSuperview] and then add the svc.view as subView of you window?

Try again removing this line: [svc.view removeFromSuperview].
Anyway if svc is you main controller you can try with
[window setRootViewController:svc] (only from iOS 4.0 and earlier version) instead of [windows addSubview:svc.view]

Comment: @Gabriele: I am removing vc and adding svc. hope that clears up the confusion ! ..will try your suggestion. thanks

Comment: eheh Ok sorry but It seemed to me a miss spell.
I don't know if you have to remove vc obligatorily but if you don't you can try with [vc presentModalViewController:svc] and when you done with svc you can use [svc dismissModalViewController] to pop the controller out from the stack

Comment: @Gabriele : thanks.. that helped..still not sure why it was not working with my old code :( ..... please update your answer so that I can accept it :)